# Elixir sass not working with @imports

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, laravel-elixir

I have a main entry point called `frontend.scss`, which has a few `@import`s.. usual stuff.

When I run `gulp`, they all compile fine. But when I run `gulp watch`, it only sees changes in the main entry point (`frontend.scss`) and not any of the `@imports`. Is there anything I need to configure for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's already a pull request on this issue. Hope it gets resolved soon.

https://github.com/laravel/elixir/pull/377